# TypeScript: tell what is the current context to an external function

Tags: javascript, casting, typescript1.6

Is there any way to tell to the TypeScript Compiler what is the current context of an external function? Preferably, on the signature of the function itself.

Currently I'm using the typecasting to solve this.

Here, an example code:

```
module ui
{
    class Hyperlink
    {
        element: HTMLAnchorElement;
        constructor(url:string,text:string){
            this.element = document.createElement("a");
            this.element.setAttribute("href",url);
            this.element.innerText = text;
            this.element.addEventListener(
                "click", 
                genericOutOfClassFunction.bind(this), <----- binds the current context
                false
            );
            // ...
        }
    }

    // [...]

    function genericOutOfClassFunction(e: Event) {
        var el = this.element; // <---------- compiler error
        // ...

        // alternatively, I've being using:
        var self = <Hyperlink>this;
        var el = self.element; // <--------- no error, but ugly =(
        // ...
    }

    // [...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use `this` parameter [[link to docs]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

You just have to declare context like You would declare function argument called `this`. In Your case it would be:

```
function genericOutOfClassFunction(this: HTMLElement, e: Event) {
  // "this" is type of HTMLElement
}
```

It might look like it adds new function argument, but it doesn't. It just sets `this` to specified Type.